# RXJS How to Convert Observable<boolean> to boolean without subscribe

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I would like to take an **Observable** and convert it to an **boolean**

Is there a standard operator for doing this? I've searched around but haven't found anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No there's not. If you want to get only the first value, just do :

```
const myBoolean;

yourObservable$.first().subscribe(myBool => myBoolean = myBool);
```